# pynput can not listen keyboard input when use some program

Tags: python, pynput

when I use Chrome, pynput works very good, it tells me which key have I pressed.
But when I use some other programes, such as Taskmgr.exe, games, It failed! What should I do?
my code:

```
from pynput import keyboard

last_event_time=time.time()
def on_press(key):
    global last_event_time
    last_event_time=time.time()
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    global last_event_time
    last_event_time=time.time()
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False
listener2 = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press)
listener2.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this particular problem for literally a year in my own code before finding the reason. If a program is launched as **elevated**, then a non elevated program such as your script cannot read the keyboard.

If it's important that you get it working, I knocked up some basic code a while ago to relaunch my script with admin rights. The file is [here](https://github.com/Peter92/MouseTracks/blob/master/mousetracks/utils/os/console.py), and its run a bit like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    console.elevate(visible=not start_minimised)
    # Do your main code here
```

Comment: Before I use console.elevate, which package should I import ?

Comment: It's the file I added as a link. It's probably not very robust but worked fine for me.

Comment: I use cmd with admin rights to run my script, it works well.Thanks for help.